# How to modify the style of proof?

Tags: spacing, theorems

I know that "proof" is predefined in latex. However, there are additional blank lines before and after the contents of proof. How can I reduce the blank line before and after proof?

I just use  the following:

```
\begin{proof}

This is the proof.

\end{proof}
```

As we can see from the figure, the space before the proof is a little large for me. I want to reduce it to the normal space.

[image]

Comment: The `proof` environment isn't predefined in LaTeX. It's defined by packages (like [`amsthm`](//ctan.org/pkg/amsthm) and others). So, depending on the package/extension you're using, there may be differing solutions. Can you provide us with a minimal document that replicates your current behaviour? It should start with `\documentclass` and end with `\end{document}`. Can you do that?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE.

Comment: Assuming that the output you show was produced by input that had blank lines separating the `\begin` and `\end` statements from the proof text, the fact that the q.e.d. box is black rather than open indicates that you did `not` use the `amsthm` package.  If this is true, the otherwise very nice answer by @Mico will probably not produce the result you are looking for.

Comment: @barbarabeeton - My hunch -- not verifiable for now, as the OP didn't show the underlying code -- is that the the code also redefines `\qedsymbol`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @Werner has already pointed out in a comment, the `proof` environment isn't defined by the LaTeX kernel. Instead, it is defined by the `amsthm` package -- and likely some other packages as well.

Assuming your document employs the `amsthm` package, you may achieve your formatting objective by placing the following code chunk in the preamble -- *after* loading `amsthm`, of course.

```
\makeatletter
\renewenvironment{proof}[1][\proofname]{\par
  \pushQED{\qed}%
  %% Replace "\topsep6\p@\@plus6\p@" with "\topsep0\p@"
  %% (or, using LaTeX-like syntax: '\setlength{\topsep}{0pt}')
  \normalfont \topsep0\p@\relax
  \trivlist
  \item[\hskip\labelsep\itshape#1\@addpunct{.}]\ignorespaces}{%
  \popQED\endtrivlist\@endpefalse
}
\makeatother
```

An importatnt thing to note is that the parameter `\topsep` controls not only the amount of vertical whitespace that's inserted *above* the `proof` environment, but also the amount of vertical whitespace that's inserted *below* the `proof` environment..

A full MWE (minimum working example and its output):

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsthm} % for 'proof' environment
\usepackage{lipsum} % for filler text

\makeatletter
\renewenvironment{proof}[1][\proofname]{\par
  \pushQED{\qed}%
  %% Replace "\topsep6\p@\@plus6\p@" with "\topsep0\p@"
  %% (or, using LaTeX-like syntax: '\setlength\topsep{0pt}')
  \normalfont \topsep0\p@\relax
  \trivlist
  \item[\hskip\labelsep\itshape#1\@addpunct{.}]\ignorespaces}{%
  \popQED\endtrivlist\@endpefalse
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\lipsum[2] % filler text
\hrule
\begin{proof}
\lipsum[2] % filler text
\end{proof}
\hrule
\lipsum[2] % filler text
\end{document}
```

Comment: Nice answer.  Unfortunately, there's extra space inserted *after* `theorem` or `defintion` environments that wouldn't be removed by omitting the space above `proof`.  (I didn't check, but think I remember that such a space will simply be the larger of the two possibilities.  Haven't got time to check though.)

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. The solution works well for me!

Comment: @barbarabeeton - I just answered the OP's question, "How can I reduce the blank [space] before and after [the] proof [environment]?"...